# Sails Js Read uploaded file content

Tags: node.js, file, sails.js

I want get content from my uploaded file. Uploaded file is just text file and i want read this file line by line

```
req.file("model").upload(function (err, uploadedFiles){
  if (err) return res.serverError(err);

  return res.json({
    message: uploadedFiles.length + ' file(s) uploaded successfully!',
    files: uploadedFiles,
    content: uploadedFiles[0] // I want to get my uploaded file content
                              // Stream or buffer
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install Local filesystem streaming binary adapter for Sails.js / Waterline

```
npm install sails-local-fs
```

in your code create fs instance

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

And now use readFile() method to get content of your file

```
fs.readFile(files[0].fd, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    return res.json(200, {message: 'Ok', data: data});
  })
```

Comment: Can i use it for xlsx file also??

Comment: Any idea if this changed? fd gets the file name and not the relative path

Answer (score 4):

You can get the file descriptor from `uploadedFiles[0].fd`

Use it to read / stream the file.

```
fs.readFile(uploadedFiles[0].fd, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        return res.json(200, {message: 'Ok', data: data});
})
```