# Upload file SailsJS

Tags: vue.js, sails.js

I'm trying to upload a text file to the server running SailsJS from a VueJS web app. I'm able to confirm that VueJS is sending the file, but I keep getting errors on the server. My code is below:

```
uploadData(req, res) {
  Logger.info(req.file('file'));

  req.file('file').upload({
    dirname:'../../tmp',
    saveAs:"hello"
  },function onUploadComplete(err,files){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      return res.serverError(err);
    }
    if(!files.length) {
      return res.serverError(new Error('No file Uploaded'))
    }
    res.ok(files);
  });
},
```

The error I'm getting is below:

```
2018-09-17T16:55:07.736Z] info:  info: Custom response `res.serverError()` called with an Error: Error: Request aborted
    at IncomingMessage.onReqAborted (/home/ubuntu/server/node_modules/multiparty/index.js:183:17)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
    at abortIncoming (_http_server.js:444:9)
    at socketOnClose (_http_server.js:437:3)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
    at TCP._handle.close (net.js:599:12)
```

What am I doing wrong? I followed instructions as per below:

[Sails Js Read uploaded file content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40371401/sails-js-read-uploaded-file-content)

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/request-req/req-file

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/file-uploads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working:

```
uploadData(req, res) {
  Logger.info(req.file('file'));

  return req.file('file').upload({
    adapter: require('skipper-disk'),
    saveAs:"hello"
  },function onUploadComplete(err,files){
    if(err){
      console.error("ERROR");
      console.log(err);
      return res.serverError(err);
    }
    if(!files.length) {
      return res.serverError(new Error('No file Uploaded'))
    }
    res.ok(files);
  });
},
```